# Noise at Corners of MATLAB's ifft2

Tags: fft, matlab, ifft

I'm trying to implement the code in [this](https://dev.epicgames.com/community/learning/tutorials/qM1o/unreal-engine-ocean-simulation) tutorial in MATLAB using MATLAB's ifft2() function instead of the algorithm used in the shader (looks to be some type of Radix-2 algorithm). It is used to compute the surface of an ocean using compute shaders in Unreal Engine.

I've confirmed I'm computing FFTGrid.DZ correctly, but when I take the inverse fast Fourier transform of it (`D = ifft2(hTilde)`) I get a lot of noise in the corners as shown below and the results don't look correct. Are there common causes for this?

[image]

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The MATLAB 2023a code I'm executing is:

```
clc; clear all; close all;

%%-- FX_OceanWater_SetInitials --%%
GridSize = 64;
HalfGridSize = GridSize/2;

% PerCascadeParameters
WindDirectionality = 1;
WindDirectionality = 1-WindDirectionality;
A = 240;
PatchLength = 2000; % [m]
Chop = 1.5;
ShortWaveCutoff = 30;
LongWaveCutoff  = 0.04;
WindTighten = 1;

% Misc
g = 9.8; % [m/s^2]
RepeatPeriod = 1000;
Time = 0.0125;
AnimationTime = mod(Time,RepeatPeriod);
BaseFreq = 2*pi/RepeatPeriod;

% WindControl
windAngle = 90;
WindDirection = [sind(windAngle);cosd(windAngle)];
WindSpeed = 44;


%%-- FX_OceanWater_SetGrids--%%
SpectrumGrid    = cell(GridSize,GridSize);
FFTGrid.DX_DY   = cell(GridSize,GridSize);
FFTGrid.DZ      = cell(GridSize,GridSize);


%%-- FX_OceanWater_PopulateSpectrum --%%
threadX  = 0:1:GridSize-1;
threadY = 0:1:GridSize-1;

% Complex Amplitudes
rng(1);
randNums = ones(4,1);%rand(4,1)*2*pi;
ComplexAmplitude = [randNums(1)*sin(randNums(1));randNums(2)*cos(randNums(2));randNums(3)*sin(randNums(3));randNums(4)*cos(randNums(4))];

% HLSL
for ii = 1:length(threadX)
    for jj = 1:length(threadY)
        % Retrive WaveVector from thread index.
        Position = [threadX(ii);threadY(jj)];
        WaveVector = [Position(1)-HalfGridSize; Position(2)-HalfGridSize];
        WaveVector = WaveVector * 2 * pi;
        
        % Our parameters for each of cascade are stored as components of a 4D vector.
        % We access them, treating 4D vector as array of 4 scalars,
        % And our Z component of thread index is the index of cascade, current compute thread belongs to.
        WaveVector = WaveVector/PatchLength;
                
        % Calculate magnitude of WaveVector
        k = norm(WaveVector,2);

        % Result is magnitude of positive and negative spectrums
        Result = [0;0];

        % Handle zero length case
        if k > 0.0001
            % Calculate direction of wave vector
            k_norm = WaveVector/k;
            
            % Calculate dampening factor for wave directions not aligning with the wind
            % Positive spectrum is in R component, negative spectrum is in G component.
            WindFactor(1) = dot( k_norm, WindDirection);
            WindFactor(2) = dot(-k_norm, WindDirection);
            WindFactorAbs = abs(WindFactor);
            WindFactorAbs = WindFactorAbs.^WindTighten;

            % Reduce magnitude of the waves, travelling in negative direction
            if WindFactor(1) <= 0
                WindFactorAbs(1) = WindFactorAbs(1)*WindDirectionality;
            end
            if WindFactor(2) <= 0
                WindFactorAbs(2) = WindFactorAbs(2)*WindDirectionality;
            end
            WindFactor = WindFactorAbs;

            % Phillips Ocean spectrum calculation
            L = WindSpeed * WindSpeed / g;
            UpperPart = exp(-1.0 / ((k * L) * (k * L)));
            Spectrum = A * UpperPart / (k * k * k * k);

            % Dampen waves, shorter than user controlled threshold
            Spectrum = Spectrum * exp(-(k*k) * ShortWaveCutoff);
            if k < LongWaveCutoff
                Spectrum = 0;
            end

            Result = sqrt(Spectrum * WindFactor);
            Result = Result / sqrt(2);
        end

        % Lastly, obtain complex amplitude/phases.
        PositiveAndNegativeSpectrum = [Result(1); Result(1); Result(2); Result(2)];
        PositiveAndNegativeSpectrum = PositiveAndNegativeSpectrum.*ComplexAmplitude;

        % And obtain conjugate of negative spectrum by flipping its imaginary part.
        PositiveAndNegativeSpectrum(4) = -1*PositiveAndNegativeSpectrum(4);

        % Prepare index of the grid, at which result will be stored and write the result.
        SpectrumGrid{ii,jj} = PositiveAndNegativeSpectrum;
    end
end


%%-- FX_OceanWater_TimeStep --%%
% HLSL
for ii = 1:length(threadX)
    for jj = 1:length(threadY)
        % Retrive WaveVector from thread index
        WaveVector = [threadX(ii)-HalfGridSize;threadY(jj)-HalfGridSize];
        WaveVector = WaveVector * 2 * pi;
        WaveVector = WaveVector/PatchLength;
        
        % Calculate magnitude of WaveVector
        k = norm(WaveVector,2);
        
        % Dispersion. Angular frequency from wave vector
        Freq = sqrt(g * k);
        
        % Quantize frequency to multiple of base frequency
        Freq = floor(Freq / BaseFreq) * BaseFreq;
        Phase = Freq * AnimationTime;

        % Load initial spectrum
        h0 = SpectrumGrid{ii,jj};

        % Calculate exponents for positive and negative spectrums
        fourier_amp         = h0(1:2);
        fourier_amp_conj    = h0(3:4);
        SineCosine = [sin(Phase);cos(Phase)];

        exponent = [SineCosine(2); SineCosine(1)];
        exponent_inv = [SineCosine(2); -SineCosine(1)];

        % Resulting displacements
        DispZ=[0;0];
        DispX=[0;0];
        DispY=[0;0];

        % Handle zero length case.
        if k > 0.000001
            %Complex multiplication of positive spectrum by exponent
            c0 = jMul(fourier_amp,exponent);

            %Complex multiplication of negative spectrum by inverse exponent
            c1 = jMul(fourier_amp_conj,exponent_inv);

            %Complex addition of positive and negative parts
            DispZ = c0 + c1;

            % Calculate horizontal displacements by projecting vertical displacement on components of wave direction
            dx = [0;WaveVector(1)/k]*Chop;
            DispX = jMul(DispZ,dx);
            
            dy = [0;  WaveVector(2)/k]*Chop;
            DispY = jMul(DispZ,dy);
        end
        FFTGrid.DX_DY{ii,jj} = [DispX;DispY];
        FFTGrid.DZ{ii,jj} = [DispZ];
    end
end



%% Compute Z
% Convert FFTGrid to complex array
for ii = 1:length(threadX)
    for jj = 1:length(threadY)
        hTilde(ii,jj) = FFTGrid.DZ{ii,jj}(1) + ii*FFTGrid.DZ{ii,jj}(2);
    end
end

%- Definitions -%
% -N/2 <= n < N/2
n = -GridSize/2:1:(GridSize/2-1);

% -M/2 <= m < M/2
m = -GridSize/2:1:(GridSize/2-1);

% Discrete spatial points
xPoints = n*PatchLength/GridSize;
zPoints = m*PatchLength/GridSize;

% x: Spatial Points
[xGrid,zGrid] = meshgrid(xPoints,zPoints);

% Compute iFFT
D = ifft2(hTilde);

%-- Draw Surface --%
s=surf(xGrid,zGrid,real(D));
s.EdgeColor = 'none';


%% User Functions
function sgn = signGrid(N,M)
    [x,y] = meshgrid(1:M,1:N) ;
    sgn = ones( M, N ) ;
    sgn(mod(x+y,2)==0) = -1 ;
end

function c = jMul(c0, c1)
    c       = zeros(2,1);
    c(1)    = c0(1)*c1(1) - c0(2)*c1(2);
    c(2)    = c0(1)*c1(2) + c0(2)*c1(1);
end
```

where `hTilde` are the Fourier amplitudes of the wave field realization.

*Update*
I believe fftshift does shift the results to the proper location, but it doesn't eliminate or explain the large spikes

`surf(xGrid,zGrid,fftshift(real(D)))`:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing an fftshift?

Comment: I could be? When are you supposed to use that?

Comment: ifft assumes your spectrum is from $[0,2\pi)$. If you generate a spectrum that's from $[-\pi,\pi)$ you need to ifftshift() it prior to performing an IFFT. Ie, if you have a sinusoid with digital frequency $0.1\pi$ and create the spectrum from $[-\pi,\pi)$, it will appear to the ifft that the frequency is actually at $0.9\pi$ unless you ifftshift.

Comment: Please read about [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then [edit] your post to include one. If we don’t know what `FFTGrid.DZ.x` is, we don’t know what you’re computing the inverse transform of.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make the code shorter while being reproducible. I'll include the code I'm running and think about a way to make it shorter

Comment: The spike just means you have a DC (zero frequency) component in the data. Unless you actively remove it, most data will have a DC component.

Comment: @PeterK., that's a good point. But I believe there should not be a DC component in the data based on how the complex exponentials are being assembled.